# List of experimental band gap

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, data

does anyone know where one can find a list, database, book of experimental bandgap values of semiconductors? Is there such a collection? Or do I need to scour papers one at a time to get the values?

Comment: NIST [has one from 1973](http://srdata.nist.gov/gateway/gateway?keyword=semiconductor) (second bullet on the right side of the page)

Comment: There's also [Landolt-Boernstein](http://www.springermaterials.com/docs/index.html) and the somewhat briefer [website of the Ioffe Institute](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/index.html).

Comment: Thanks guys! I think those are the best sources available! Cheers! =)

Comment: Have you Googled it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted to post this as a comment but due to a lack of points I cannot do so.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_materials

This is a pretty big list of semiconductors including their bandgaps and whether they are direct or not.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think this should be a comment. It answers the question, so it should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a comment into an answer so the question will hopefully quit popping to the front page.

Three useful sources are

- [NIST](http://srdata.nist.gov/gateway/gateway?keyword=semiconductor) (Thanks to user Kyle Kanos)
- [Landoldt-Boernstein](http://www.springermaterials.com/docs/index.html)
- The [Ioffe Institute](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/index.html)